# How to characterize the random variables $X$ with values on $[0,1]$ such that $X \stackrel{d}{=} |2X-1|$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I can only think of three distributions with this probability: $X\sim\mathrm{Unif}(0,1)$ and the degenerate distributions $X = 1$ and $X=\frac13$, but I suspect there ought to be other distributions with this property. If there were only one, I might think it would be unique. But I found three different distributions that don't seem to have much in common, so I suspect that these are examples of a larger family of distributions with this property. For example, I can imagine there exists some way to continuous shift between these three while preserving $X\stackrel{d}{=} |2X-1|$.

Comment: A trivial way to get some more examples from the degenerate ones is to set $X = 1_A + \frac{1}{3} 1_{A^c}$ for an arbitrary measurable set $A$ in your probability space.

Comment: Indeed! I did not think of that. It may be this is more complicated than I originally anticipated.